# Text wrap - have two text boxes behave differently with same object

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap

I have two text boxes that I would like to have behave differently around an object.  The title text box I want to run across the graphic object (so ignoring the text wrap I setup on the object) and the other is the first paragraph of text that I want to behave according to the text wrap I setup.
How do I do that?
See photo - I want the word DOTS to be on top of the DOT.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

NVM....just saw the "ignore text wrap" checkbox on the text frame options!  Problem solved.

Open the Text Frame Options menu:

[image: options]

Check this box:

[image: check]

Comment: Hey user58265, if your own answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the correct one and leaving the info for posterity :) Thanks!